# VM Communicating with Another VM

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I have two separate VMs created with VMWare Fusion.  One is running Windows 7. The other is running Centos.  I have an application on the Centos VM that needs to communicate with resources on the Windows VM.  Does anyone know how I can setup communication between the VMs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Fusion virtual machines all [get IP addresses from DHCP by default](https://mikewest.org/2009/05/static-ips-in-vmware-fusion-guests). So, just use what you would to get resources if they were different machines.